# I got this error 'TypeError: ingredients.push is not a function'

Tags: json

I'm still learning about JSON GET and POST and I'm using Insomnia Designer as my dev tools.

Here is my code:

```
var ingredients = [
  {
      "id": "232323",
      "text": "Eggs"
  },
  {
      "id": "121212",
      "text": "Milk"
  },
  {
      "id": "45464",
      "text": "Bacon"
  },
  {
      "id": "67686",
      "text": "Onion"
  } 
];

app.post('/', function (request, response) {
  var ingredients = request.body;
  if (!ingredients || ingredients.text == "") {
    response.status(500).send({error: "Your ingredient must have a text"});
  } else {
    ingredients.push(ingredients);
    response.status(200).send(ingredients);
  }
});
```

When I try to execute the code, it shows an error at line `'ingredients.push(ingredients);'`

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Please provide the JS code where you push into ingredients. Thanks

Comment: {
 "id": "787867",
 "text": "Cheese"
}

Comment: What’s the error ? Or error message ? Please share

Comment: Here is the error:

Comment: TypeError: ingredients.push is not a function
    at /Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/server.js:37:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-

Comment: API/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/shdwstrm/Desktop/first-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Comment: I have added the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's due to the same name that you've used, try the below code:

```
app.post('/', function (request, response) {
  var _ingredients = request.body;
  if (!ingredients || ingredients.text == "") {
    response.status(500).send({error: "Your ingredient must have a text"});
  } else {
    _ingredients.push(ingredients);
    response.status(200).send(_ingredients);
  }
});
```

It's always a good practice to use a **underscore** ('_') to differentiate between *local and global* variables.

Answer (score 1):

request.body could be an object. You need to specify like this.

```
var ingredients = request.body.ingredients;
```

**Try this:**

```
app.post('/', function (request, response) {
var ingredients = request.body.ingredients;

if (!ingredients || ingredients.text == "") {
        response.status(500).send({error: "Your ingredient must have a text"});
} else {
   ingredients.push(ingredients);
    response.status(200).send(ingredients);
}
```

Hope this helps.